# How to find the fitted value in cv.glmnet or glmnet function in R?

Tags: r, glmnet, lasso-regression

Suppose I have generated the following data set and fitted the model using `cv.glmnet` function in `R`.

```
library(glmnet)
means <- c(-1, 1.3, 0.6, 2, 1.5, -0.7, 2.5)
size <- c(50, 50, 100, 200, 350, 50, 200)


t = list()
  for (i in 1:length(means)) {
   t[[i]] <- c(rnorm(size[i],mean = means[i],sd = 0.5))
  }
y <- c(unlist(t))
plot(y,type = 'l')

lower_tri <- function(i){ 
  a <- matrix(1,i,i)
  a[upper.tri(a)] <- 0
  return(a)
}
x <- lower_tri(sum(size))[,2:sum(size)]

cv_fit <- cv.glmnet(x,y)
```

How to find the fitted value using `cv_fit1`? I used `fitted()` function for `lm` model.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `Error: object 'cv.glmnet' not found`

Comment: @42- it is under package `library(glmnet)`

Comment: Come on,  take the hint. [Edit] your code in the body of the question.

Answer (score -1):

Asking for the `fitted` values of a `cv.glmnet`-object from pkg `glmnet` is wrong headed. Cross-validation is being done on a relatively wide variety of models with varying structures, so it's not really doing anything equivalent to `glm` which has a single model and a single result. The goal of `cv.glmnet` it to give you results that let you choose the optimal level of complexity of the `glmnet` procedure given the nature of your data. It is a step on the way to choosing a glmnet model, i.e. choosing lambda. You could use this to get a prediction:

```
 predict( glmnet(x,y), s=cv_fit$lambda.min )
```

I don't see the example offered as being particularly useful to support further discussion since it appears rather "degenerate" with a minimal level of complexity.